# Change SharerPoint 2019 User Profile Service Application Database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

For some reasons we would like to change the User Profile Service Application Database. Can somebody point the correct approach to do it.

For e.g. Current user profile service application is hosted on SQL Server A. Now we want to move all the Databases related to User Profile Service Application to SQL Server B. We have My site and content database hosted on SQL Server A and we want to keep them there.

Answer (score 0):

We could not change the existing UPA database server in SharePoint server.
[image]
We suggest you back up and restore the three databases: profile database, social database, and synchronization database to SQL Server B, then create a new UPA to specify SQL server B as the database server, use three restored databases in SQL server B.

Comment: Thanks. Will this restore all the custom settings such as Mysite, Audience and other settings of the UPA?

Comment: The answer is no, before upgrading the My Site Host and the personal site collections, you must upgrade the Managed Metadata service application, and then the User Profile Service application, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-my-sites?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I am not upgrading.  I just want to change the Sql server instance used by UPA.